# Image editor component in Flex / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, image, editor, image-manipulation

I'm looking for a simple Flex or JavaScript based image editing component which can be embedded in a web application. It shouldn't be a web service but rather a component that I can download and customize (i18n etc.).

I only need some basic features: most important is cropping, optional features would be rotating and adjusting brightness/contrast.

Basically something like splashup.com, but as an open source application rather than a web-service.

Thanks a lot in advance for any hints!

-- Andreas

Answer (score 1):

There is [pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/).

> Pixastic is a JavaScript library which allows you to perform a variety of operations, filters and fancy effects on images using just a bit of JavaScript.

Be sure to read the [documentation](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/) to make sure the operations you are looking to perform are supported by all browsers.  There are some issues with IE.

They have a [editor](http://editor.pixastic.com/) you can try.  It shows off some of the features.

Comment: Pixastic seems to have disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Your question suggests you want an out of the box solution, or at least a base to stand on.

Quick Google search reveals [editImage](http://faindu.wordpress.com/2008/05/23/free-flex-component-editimage-03/).  This doesn't look polished or bug free, however building on this or rolling your own should not be difficult.

Here is a good article on [Image Manipulation in Flex](http://www.insideria.com/2008/03/image-manipulation-in-flex.html).  Towards the end of it read "Cropping, Panning and Zooming", your basically looking at 5 lines of code.  I think you might even be happier building this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers!

I ended up customizing and extending this component:

http://blog.mediablur.com/2008/02/20/flex-image-cropping-component/